# Adding a column by variably replicating list elements: looking for an elegant solution

Tags: r

I have some data organised as multiple measurements per trial per subject per group:

```
subject <- rep(c(1:6),each=4)
group <- c(rep("group1", 8),rep("group2",16))
measurement <- c("measure1","measure2")
trial <- rep(c(1:2),each=2)
df <- data.frame(subject,group,trial,measurement)
```

In a separate list I have the items administered in the trials:

```
items <- list(c("A","B"),c("C","D"))
```

I'd like to add the items as administered in a separate column, so that ultimately, it looks like this:

```
subject  group trial measurement item
      1 group1     1    measure1    A
      1 group1     1    measure2    A
      1 group1     2    measure1    B
      1 group1     2    measure2    B
      2 group1     1    measure1    A
      2 group1     1    measure2    A
      2 group1     2    measure1    B
      2 group1     2    measure2    B
      3 group2     1    measure1    C
      3 group2     1    measure2    C
      3 group2     2    measure1    D
      3 group2     2    measure2    D
      4 group2     1    measure1    C
      4 group2     1    measure2    C
...
```

So essentially I want to replicate the vectors in `items` by `df$group`, so that  `items[1]` is replicated across group1 and `items[2]` across group2 (with each element of the vector appearing as many times as there are measurements per item).

I'm looking for a general solution: the number of groups, the number of subjects in each group, and the number of measurements per item is variable. However, the vectors in `items` are always of identical length, and the total number of observations per group is always a multiple of the number of items.

I would prefer a solution that doesn't use a for-loop (I can do that, but I'm trying to find a faster and more elegant solution). I have a feeling that some combination of `rep`, `seq_along` and `lapply` will easily solve this but I'm not sure how to use these together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is particularly elegant, but it should be fairly flexible, assuming that your data is regular as in the example and it also uses `lapply` and `rep`:

```
# get a count of each group, divide by the number of repetitions
# which is (item length * measurement count)
counts <- table(df$group) / length(items[[i]] * length(unique(df$measurement))
# print the vector
unlist(lapply(1:length(counts), 
         function(i) rep(items[[i]], counts[i], each=2)))
#  or add the vector to your data
df$item <- unlist(lapply(1:length(counts), 
                    function(i) rep(items[[i]], counts[i], each=2)))
```

This answer benefited from input from the OP, @strangeloop.

Comment: The data is indeed regular, but this solution replicates the vector without taking into account that each element should appear as many times as there are measurements. I guess there needs to be an `each` argument in `rep()`.

Comment: Got this working in a slightly more flexible way (incorporating the possibility of different numbers of items and measurements):

`measurements <- length(unique(t.tidy$measurement))`

`counts <- table(t.tidy$setname) / length(sets[[1]]) / measurements`

`t.tidy$item <- unlist(lapply(1:length(counts), function(i) rep(sets[[i]], counts[i], each=measurements)))`

Answer (score 3):

We can `split` the 'df' by 'group' into a `list`, create the 'item' column in each of the `list` elements using corresponding 'items' `list` being passed to `Map` with the 'trial' as the numeric index.

```
do.call(rbind, Map(function(x,y)
           transform(x, item= y[x$trial]), split(df, df$group), items))
```

---

Or `merge` with the original dataset after converting the 'items' to a 'data.frame' (using `stack`) and creating the 'trial' column.

```
merge(df, transform(setNames(stack(setNames(items, unique(df$group))), 
                        c("item", "group")), trial = 1:2))
```

Comment: Gee, learn something new everyday. The first one is short and sweet, though it creates unwieldy rownames (and I find it a bit hard to wrap my mind around `Map` but that's probably just me). The `merge` solution spreads the item vector across all rows in a group, but doesn't replicate it by measurement as needed.